# Instantiating JAX-WS service with WSDL from url and authentication

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

When instantiating a JAX-WS service client like this:

```
Service s = new Service(new URL("http://www.example.com/ws?wsdl"),
                        new QName("http://www.example.com/ws", "WebService"));
```

the WSDL from that location will be retrieved.

However if that location requires basic HTTP authentication, the line above will fail with an `HTTP 401 Authentication` error.

If I do not wish to keep the WSDL as a local copy and want to use the above way of creating the client, what changes do I need to make in order to pass the required credentials?

Comment: One thought (so not posting as answer) - how about `new URL("http://username:password@www.example.com/ws?wsdl")` ?

Comment: You could try calling [Authenticator.setDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html#setDefault-java.net.Authenticator-) early in your program.  The only catch is, you may not have permission to do that in some environments, such as Java EE.

Comment: thanks, I'll try both suggestions and let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

You can **seperate the complexity** of webservices and authentication as follows:

- download the URL at runtime (guarentees the latest version)
- store it in a **temporary file**
- next initialize the Service using the temporary file

Downloading files with basic-authentication can be achieved in several ways. **Here follows an example with JSoup:**

```
// create authentication header (necessary for some websites)
String base64login = null;
if ((pUsername != null) && (pPassword != null))
{
  String login = pUsername + ":" + pPassword;
  base64login = String.valueOf(com.jidesoft.utils.Base64.encodeBytes(login.getBytes()));
}

//Open a URL Stream
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(path);
if (base64login != null) connection = connection.header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64login);
if (pRetries != 0) connection.timeout(5000);
Connection.Response resultImageResponse = connection.ignoreContentType(true).execute();

// output here
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(localFile);
out.write(resultImageResponse.bodyAsBytes());
out.close();
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258844/problem-with-downloading-file-from-server-that-uses-basic-http-authentication-fr)'s an example with Apache HttpClient, which is very popular. One of the choices to make, is the fact that there are several Base64 encoding libraries.

A **bonus** to this approach, is that you can compare the downloaded file with the previously stored file. This gives you the ability to print warnings when changes were made.